# Debugging a native application with GDB on Android

Tags: android, debugging, gdb

I have a native C++ app which is supposed to run on an Android device. The application crashes at the startup, most likely when calling a function from a linked library. I am trying to debug it with gdb, but I can't succeed.

I am starting gdbserver on the Android device on some arbitrarily picked port (2000):

```
shell@msm8996: gdbserver :2000 my_app
Process my_app created; pid = 3420
Listening on port 2000
```

Now I am trying to attach to this process on my Host system (Windows 7) with gdb that was provided in Android-NDK.

```
C:\> gdb
(gdb) attach 3420
Can't attach to process.
(gdb) target remote :2000
:2000: The system tried to join a drive to a directory on a joined drive.
```

What is the problem?

**EDIT:**
Prior to running gdb I forwarded the port 2000 using adb:

```
adb forward tcp:2000 tcp:2000
```

This at least helped me to establish some communication, but:

```
(gdb) target remote :2000
Remote debugging using :2000
warning: Architecture rejected target-supplied description
Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: 00000000000000000000000000000...
```

On the device side:

```
Listening on port 2000
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
readchar: Got EOF
Remote side has terminated connection.  GDBserver will reopen the connection.
Listening on port 2000
```

Answer (score 3):

You are most probably using different architecture / version of gdb. When you start the gdb, it displays a line like (I am showing what my GDB shows):

> This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu
>   --target=arm-Linux-android"

Check if this matches with your phone's architecture.
Downloading the correct GDB version may solve your problem.